# SQL count rows where id = x and other max(id) grouped on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to count rows in one table where the field event_id = 17 and their isn't any other record in the table with higher g_event_id and the same value for prim_cid. My table contains events for phone calls. All events for the same call share the field "prim_cid". If the field event_id = 17 i know that the call is in queuee , but as soon its answered an new entry in table (same prim_cid) but other event_id occur. So i need to count the rows with event_id = 17 with has no later record with same prim_cid.

My table:

events:

```
g_event_id   prim_cid   event_id   event_time
----------   --------   --------   ----------
1            1          16         2016-10-21 16:00:00
2            1          17         2016-10-21 16:00:01
3            1          18         2016-10-21 16:00:02
4            2          15         2016-10-21 16:01:01
5            2          17         2016-10-21 16:01:02
6            3          16         2016-10-21 16:02:01
7            3          17         2016-10-21 16:02:02
8            3          18         2016-10-21 16:02:38
```

From this i like to get the result:

```
1
```

(as only prim_cid 2 has no higher record on the field g_event_id)
Also i would like to do an select where i get the record like:

```
g_event_id   prim_cid   event_id   event_time
----------   --------   --------   ----------
5            2          17         2016-10-21 16:01:02
```

In another sql select of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count prim_cids who "know" an event_id 17 but have no other g_event_id that is higher, than that of the 17-event. This translates directly into SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seventeens.`prim_cid`)
FROM `events` AS seventeens
  LEFT JOIN `events` AS laters ON (seventeens.`prim_cid` = laters.`prim_cid` AND laters.`g_event_id` > seventeens.`g_event_id`)
WHERE seventeens.`event_id` = 17
  AND ISNULL(laters.`prim_cid`)
```

In order to fulfill your second statement you would use the following SELECT clause for the same statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT seventeens.* 
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error: Error executing query.
Column 'prim_cid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Changed it to 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seventeens.prim_cid)
    FROM `events` AS seventeens
    LEFT JOIN `events` AS laters ON (seventeens.`prim_cid` =         laters.`prim_cid` AND laters.`g_event_id` > seventeens.`g_event_id`)
    WHERE seventeens.`event_id` = 17
    AND ISNULL(laters.`prim_cid`)

Works!  Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The prefix got lost in writing.

Answer (score 1):

here you go :)

```
SELECT COUNT(ev1.prim_cid)
FROM events ev1
WHERE ev1.event_id = 17
AND (SELECT prim_cid 
            FROM events 
            WHERE g_event_id > ev1.g_event_id 
            AND prim_cid = ev1.prim_cid) IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is actually a better approach than the accepted answer because it does not use `count(distinct)`.  However, this version would be better written using `not exists`.

Comment: Many thanks @Gordon In terms of performance I think NOT EXISTS and IS NULL is just the same, however in terms of readability I agree that NOT EXISTS is better.

Comment: They only happen to be the same in this case, because `prim_cid` cannot be `NULL` (presumably).

Comment: Have tried this out but it doesn't work, the result is always empty.